# How can I validate date in LWC datapicker - lightning-input-field component

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components

How can I validate and set max date - which can't be a future date in new LWC syntax

```
<lightning-input-field variant="label-hidden" field-name="Date_of_Birth"></lightning-input-field>
```

I tried max attribute but it doesn't work for this component - is there any way to validate date in this component or I need to use other one for this particular input.

Comment: I think you need to use a validation rule server-side... of course this is not the greatest user experience, so the other option is using a regular date field - which of course won't play well with your form. Sigh.

Answer (score 0):

you can always use a validation rule .The other way around is in the `onsubmit()` method use `event.preventDefault();`  check the value of the field under consideration if the validation fails to display a toast with the custom error message